# How to use as vuetify theme colors in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I created a nuxt app with the create nuxt app, at the time of creation I selected the vuetify ramework.
In the file **nuxt.config.js** there is an object with the configuration of the colors of a theme.

```js
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      themes: {
        mainTheme: {
          primary: '#8B0000',
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to look for documentation on how to use these colors in my vue component but I'm quite confused about that and so far I haven't been able to.

```html
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="#8B0000">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <h1 class="title">Abner Matheus</h1>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style scoped>
.title {
  color: azure;
}
</style>
```

**I want the color property on my v-toolbar to receive one of my theme's colors.**
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: color is a prop, not an attribute. Try `<v-toolbar :color="#8B0000">`

Comment: Please update your question to indicate the versions of Nuxt and Vuetify that you're using. Each of them has differences between major versions 2 and 3 that would change what the correct answer is. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `color="primary"`:

```html
<template>
  <v-toolbar color="primary">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <h1 class="title">Abner Matheus</h1>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

for other elements you may use:

```html
<span class="primary--text">Text</span>
```

See [Colors](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#colors) for more details.

Comment: does not work, the primary brings me a blue, different from the color that I put in the primary of the theme in the file nuxt.config.js.

Comment: @AbnerMatheus I'm not sure about your `mainTheme` key in your configuration. From [document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/) it should be `light` or `dark`. Do you have a link to document or article about that?